# Add variable to object path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object, variables

I am working on a project in react native. I need to put variable in object path.

[image: code1]

[image: code2]

```
{globalDegerler.systemText.tr.welcomeMsg}
{globalDegerler.systemText    {checkLanguage}   welcomeMsg}
```

I keep the variable of the selected language in the system. How can I add this to the object path?

Can I add a variable I want instead of variable in the code2 photo?

Comment: Use the square bracket notation

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe what you want to do is this:

`{globalDegerler.systemText[checkLanguage].welcomeMsg}`